# have you seen Golang Regexp not find all occurrences?

Tags: html, regex, go, html-parsing

I have a sample where I'm trying to remove all lines of a file where it is empty (newline only or spaces and newline). I thought I would be able to do this easily with a simple `^\s*$`. The file sample I have is 724 lines long with 182 occurences of this pattern when I use `grep -e '^\s*$' samplefile | wc -l` and I can simply add the `-v` flag and redirect the output to get the contents with the extra lines removed.

In Go 1.12.4 I try:

```
dat, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("./samplefile")
ioutil.WriteFile("eventbody", []byte(strings.Split(string(dat), "</head>")[1]), 0555)

regNewline := regexp.MustCompile(`(?ms)^\s*$`)
d := regNewline.ReplaceAll(dat, []byte(""))
ioutil.WriteFile("./emptyremoved", d, 0555)
```

And the resulting file is 143 occurrences shy of actually doing what I want. The sample file is just an HTML page. The whole reason I did this to begin with was because I could not get the `golang.org/x/net/html` package to parse the HTML and step through the Tokens to get the data I want (table rows) and settled on some re to try to solve my problem but I'm still hitting a dead end.

Sample file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>SourceManagementboard</title>
    <style>
      @font-face {
        font-family: 'Open Sans';
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 400;
        src: local('Open Sans'), local('OpenSans'), url(/static/fonts/Open_Sans.woff) format('woff');
      }
      input[type=text] {
        width: 130px;
        border: 2px solid #f96302;
        -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
        transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
      }
      input[type=text]:focus {
        width: 270px;
      }
    </style>
    
    <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <link href="/static/Semantic-UI-2.1.8/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.13/css/dataTables.semanticui.min.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    
    <link href="/static/css/c3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/static/css/SourceManagementboard.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    
      <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
      <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.13/js/dataTables.semanticui.min.js"></script>
      
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.7.0/moment.min.js"></script>
      
    
    
      <script src="/static/js/timestamps.js"></script>
    
    <script src="/static/Semantic-UI-2.1.8/semantic.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/lists.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/scroll.top.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/c3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/jquery-tablesort-v.0.0.11/jquery.tablesort.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".ui.dropdown").dropdown();
            $.getScript('/static/js/lists.js')
            $.getScript('/static/js/tables.js')
             
          })
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function jumpToServerPage() {
            var myserver = document.getElementById("serverJump").value;
            if (myserver == "*.foo.com"){
                var jumpto = "/node/" + myserver;
                window.location = jumpto;
            else {
                var jumpto = "/node/" + myserver + ".foo.com";
                window.location = jumpto;
            }
        }
    </script>
     

<!-- begin usabilla live embed code -->
<script type="text/javascript">/*{literal}<![CDATA[*/window.lightningjs||function(c){function g(b,d){d&&(d+=(/\?/.test(d)?"&":"?")+"lv=1");c[b]||function(){var i=window,h=document,j=b,g=h.location.protocol,l="load",k=0;(function(){function b(){a.P(l);a.w=1;c[j]("_load")}c[j]=function(){function m(){m.id=e;return c[j].apply(m,arguments)}var b,e=++k;b=this&&this!=i?this.id||0:0;(a.s=a.s||[]).push([e,b,arguments]);m.then=function(b,c,h){var d=a.fh[e]=a.fh[e]||[],j=a.eh[e]=a.eh[e]||[],f=a.ph[e]=a.ph[e]||[];b&&d.push(b);c&&j.push(c);h&&f.push(h);return m};return m};var a=c[j]._={};a.fh={};a.eh={};a.ph={};a.l=d?d.replace(/^\/\//,(g=="https:"?g:"http:")+"//"):d;a.p={0:+new Date};a.P=function(b){a.p[b]=new Date-a.p[0]};a.w&&b();i.addEventListener?i.addEventListener(l,b,!1):i.attachEvent("on"+l,b);var q=function(){function b(){return["<head></head><",c,' onload="var d=',n,";d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].",d,"(d.",g,"('script')).",i,"='",a.l,"'\"></",c,">"].join("")}var c="body",e=h[c];if(!e)return setTimeout(q,100);a.P(1);var d="appendChild",g="createElement",i="src",k=h[g]("div"),l=k[d](h[g]("div")),f=h[g]("iframe"),n="document",p;k.style.display="none";e.insertBefore(k,e.firstChild).id=o+"-"+j;f.frameBorder="0";f.id=o+"-frame-"+j;/MSIE[ ]+6/.test(navigator.userAgent)&&(f[i]="javascript:false");f.allowTransparency="true";l[d](f);try{f.contentWindow[n].open()}catch(s){a.domain=h.domain,p="javascript:var d="+n+".open();d.domain='"+h.domain+"';",f[i]=p+"void(0);"}try{var r=f.contentWindow[n];r.write(b());r.close()}catch(t){f[i]=p+'d.write("'+b().replace(/"/g,String.fromCharCode(92)+'"')+'");d.close();'}a.P(2)};a.l&&setTimeout(q,0)})()}();c[b].lv="1";return c[b]}var o="lightningjs",k=window[o]=g(o);k.require=g;k.modules=c}({});
window.usabilla_live = lightningjs.require("usabilla_live", "//w.usabilla.com/521b4f1b8dd9.js");
/*]]>{/literal}*/</script>
<!-- end usabilla live embed code -->

     
  </head>


  <body>
    <div class="ui doubling stackable inverted large menu" style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 20px;">
      <div class="title item" style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
        <a href="/">
          <img src="/static/icons/fldlogo.svg">
        </a>
      </div>
      <a class="item" href="/">Report Board</a>
      <a class="item" href="/search">StackRepo</a>
      <a class="item" href="/validate">Validate Info</a>
      <a class="item" href="/patching">Patching Status</a>
      <div class="ui item dropdown">More<i class="dropdown icon"></i>
          <div class="menu">
              <a class="item" href="/nodes">Nodes</a>
              <a class="item" href="/"></a>
              <a class="item" href="/reports">Reports</a>
              <a class="item" href="/metrics">Metrics</a>
              <a class="item" href="/inventory">Inventory</a>
              <a class="item" href="/catalogerrors">Catalog Errors</a>
              <a class="item" href="/radiator">Radiator</a>
              <a class="item" href="/query">Query</a>
              <a class="item" href="/module">Module Reporting</a>
              <a class="item" href="/grid_versions">Grid Versions</a>
              <a class="item" href="/summary">Core State</a>
          </div>
      </div>
      <form method="POST" class="item" action="/serverjump" name="serverjump">
          <input class="item" type="submit" value="Go" style="background-color: #f96302; color: black;">
          <input class="item" style="color: orange;" id="server_name" name="server_name"
              type="text" placeholder="Jump to a Server info page" value="">
      </form>
      <div class="item right">
          <div class="ui item dropdown">
              <b>S</b>
              
              <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
              <div class="menu">
                  <a class="item " href="/%2A/report/myserv.foo.com/58964efb70ab87610ff4ce3fdbf46ce7dea54dac">All servers</a>
                  
                      <a class="item "
                          href="/production/report/myserv.foo.com/58964efb70ab87610ff4ce3fdbf46ce7dea54dac">Datacenter</a>
                      <a class="item active"
                          href="/report/myserv.foo.com/58964efb70ab87610ff4ce3fdbf46ce7dea54dac">S</a>
                  
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui grid padding-bottom">
        <div class="one wide column"></div>
        <div class="fourteen wide column">
            
<h1>Summary</h1>
<table class='ui basic table'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Certname</th>
      <th>Configuration version</th>
      <th>Start time</th>
      <th>End time</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/node/myserv.foo.com">myserv.foo.com</a></td>
      <td>
        <p>1581366405</p>

      </td>
      <td rel="utctimestamp">
        2020-02-10 20:26:02.286000+00:00
      </td>
      <td rel="utctimestamp">
        2020-02-10 20:27:33.971000+00:00
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<style>
    .button {
      display: inline-block;
      border-radius: 4px;
      background-color: #f4511e;
      border: none;
      color: #FFFFFF;
      transition: all 0.5s;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .button span {
      cursor: pointer;
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      transition: 0.5s;
    }
    .button span:after {
      content: '»';
      position: absolute;
      opacity: 0;
      top: 0;
      right: -20px;
      transition: 0.5s;
    }
    .button:hover span {
      padding-right: 25px;
    }
    .button:hover span:after {
      opacity: 1;
      right: 0;
    }
</style>

<h1>Events <a href="/download_report/myserv.foo.com/58964efb70ab87610ff4ce3fdbf46ce7dea54dac/events"><button style="float: right;" class="ui grey button"><span>Download</span></button></a></h1>
<table class='ui basic compact fixed wrapped table'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="eight wide">Resource</th>
      <th class="two wide">Status</th>
      <th class="two wide">Changed From</th>
      <th class="four wide">Changed To</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    
    
      <tr id='event-1' class='ui line changed'>
    
      <td>Exec[/bin/ksh -c &#39;source /usr/local/bin/src.host; /opt/sr/su/bin/sr-db-sc 1249 N COM&#39;]</td>
      <td>success</td>
      <td>notrun</td>
      <td>[u&#39;0&#39;]</td>
    </tr>
    
    
      <tr id='event-2' class='ui line failed'>
    
      <td>Package[sr-kd-if]</td>
      <td>failure</td>
      <td>1.22-1</td>
      <td>2.0-2</td>
    </tr>
    
    
      <tr id='event-3' class='ui line changed'>
    
      <td>Exec[yum_trex reconfig]</td>
      <td>success</td>
      <td>notrun</td>
      <td>[u&#39;0&#39;]</td>
    </tr>
    
    
      <tr id='event-4' class='ui line changed'>
    
      <td>Exec[yum_trex config]</td>
      <td>success</td>
      <td>notrun</td>
      <td>[u&#39;0&#39;]</td>
    </tr>
    
    
      <tr id='event-5' class='ui line changed'>
    
      <td>Exec[rpm_import_stflag]</td>
      <td>success</td>
      <td>notrun</td>
      <td>[u&#39;0&#39;]</td>
    </tr>
    
    
      <tr id='event-6' class='ui line changed'>
    
      <td>Exec[RK sed on agent_flag]</td>
      <td>success</td>
      <td>notrun</td>
      <td>[u&#39;0&#39;]</td>
    </tr>
    
  </tbody>
</table>

<h1>Logs <a href="/download_report/myserv.foo.com/58964efb70ab87610ff4ce3fdbf46ce7dea54dac/logs"><button style="float: right;" class="ui grey button"><span>Download</span></button></a></h1>
<table class='ui basic compact fixed wrapped table'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Timestamp</th>
      <th>Source</th>
      <th>Tags</th>
      <th>Message</th>
      <th>Location</th>
    <tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    
      
        <tr class='warning'>
      
        <td rel="utctimestamp">2020-02-10T15:26:07.109-05:00</td>
        <td>SourceManagement</td>
        <td>warning</td>
        <td>Unable to fetch my node definition, but the agent run will continue:</td>
        
          <td></td>
        
      </tr>
    
      
        <tr class='warning'>
      
        <td rel="utctimestamp">2020-02-10T15:26:07.109-05:00</td>
        <td>SourceManagement</td>
        <td>warning</td>
        <td>Could not intern from application/json: Could not find a directory environment named &#39;env&#39; anywhere in the path: /etc/SourceManagement/code/environments. Does the directory exist?</td>
        
          <td></td>
        
      </tr>
    
      
        <tr class='positive'>
      
        <td rel="utctimestamp">2020-02-10T15:26:07.110-05:00</td>
        <td>SourceManagement</td>
        <td>info</td>
        <td>Retrieving plugin</td>
        
          <td></td>
        
      </tr>
    
      
        <tr class='positive'>
      
        <td rel="utctimestamp">2020-02-10T15:26:07.326-05:00</td>
        <td>SourceManagement</td>
        <td>info</td>
        <td>Retrieving plugin</td>
        
          <td></td>
        
      </tr>
    
      
        <tr class='positive'>
      
        <td rel="utctimestamp">2020-02-10T15:26:08.349-05:00</td>
        <td>SourceManagement</td>
        <td>info</td>
        <td>Retrieving locales</td>
        
          <td></td>
        
      </tr>
    
      
        <tr class='positive'>
      
        <td rel="utctimestamp">2020-02-10T15:26:08.572-05:00</td>
        <td>SourceManagement</td>
        <td>info</td>
        <td>Loading </td>
        
          <td></td>
        
      </tr>
    
      
        <tr class='positive'>
      
        <td rel="utctimestamp">2020-02-10T15:27:19.334-05:00</td>
        <td>SourceManagement</td>
        <td>info</td>
        <td>Caching catalog for myserv.foo.com</td>
        
          <td></td>
        
      </tr>
    
      
        <tr class='positive'>
      
        <td rel="utctimestamp">2020-02-10T15:27:20.824-05:00</td>
        <td>SourceManagement</td>
        <td>info</td>
        <td>Applying configuration version &#39;1581366405&#39;</td>
        
          <td></td>
        
      </tr>
    
      
        <tr class='positive'>
      
        <td rel="utctimestamp">2020-02-10T15:27:26.979-05:00</td>
        <td>/Stage[main]/RK::V1_0_1/Exec[RK sed on agent_flags.conf]/returns</td>
        <td>notice, exec, class, rk::v1_0_1, rk, v1_0_1</td>
        <td>executed successfully</td>
        
          <td>/etc/SourceManagement/code/environments/env/modules/rk/manifests/v1_0_1.pp:25</td>
        
      </tr>
    
      
        <tr class='positive'>
      
        <td rel="utctimestamp">2020-02-10T15:27:26.980-05:00</td>
        <td>/Stage[main]/RK::V1_0_1/Exec[RK sed on agent_flags.conf]</td>
        <td>info, exec, class, rk::v1_0_1, rk, v1_0_1</td>
        <td>Scheduling refresh of Service[rkagents]</td>
        
          <td>/etc/SourceManagement/code/environments/env/modules/rk/manifests/v1_0_1.pp:25</td>
        
      </tr>
    
      
        <tr class='positive'>
      
        <td rel="utctimestamp">2020-02-10T15:27:27.492-05:00</td>
        <td>/Stage[main]/RK::V1_0_1/Service[rkagents]</td>
        <td>notice, service, rkagents, class, rk::v1_0_1, rk, v1_0_1</td>
        <td>Triggered &#39;refresh&#39; from 1 event</td>
        
          <td>/etc/SourceManagement/code/environments/env/modules/rk/manifests/v1_0_1.pp:33</td>
        
      </tr>
    
      
        <tr class='positive'>
      
        <td rel="utctimestamp">2020-02-10T15:27:29.030-05:00</td>
        <td>/Stage[main]/tr::V1_0_5::Config/Exec[rpm_import_tr]/returns</td>
        <td>notice, exec, rpm_import_tr, class, tr::v1_0_5::config, tr, v1_0_5, config, tr::v1_0_5</td>
        <td>executed successfully</td>
        
          <td>/etc/SourceManagement/code/environments/env/modules/tanium/manifests/v1_0_5/config.pp:40</td>
        
      </tr>
    
      
        <tr class='positive'>
      
        <td rel="utctimestamp">2020-02-10T15:27:35.083-05:00</td>
        <td>/Stage[main]/Toolrental_trex_svc/Exec[yum_trex config]/returns</td>
        <td>notice, exec, class, toolrental_trex_svc</td>
        <td>executed successfully</td>
        
          <td>/etc/SourceManagement/code/environments/env/modules/toolrental_trex_svc/manifests/init.pp:7</td>
        
      </tr>
    
      
        <tr class='positive'>
      
        <td rel="utctimestamp">2020-02-10T15:27:35.101-05:00</td>
        <td>/Stage[main]/Toolrental_trex_svc/Exec[yum_trex reconfig]/returns</td>
        <td>notice, exec, class, toolrental_trex_svc</td>
        <td>executed successfully</td>
        
          <td>/etc/SourceManagement/code/environments/env/modules/toolrental_trex_svc/manifests/init.pp:17</td>
        
      </tr>
    
      
        <tr class='error'>
      
        <td rel="utctimestamp">2020-02-10T15:27:40.113-05:00</td>
        <td>SourceManagement</td>
        <td>err</td>
        <td>Could not update: Execution of &#39;/usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y update sr-kd-if-2.0-2&#39; returned 1: Error Downloading Packages:
  jq-1.3-2.el6.x86_64: failed to retrieve getPackage/jq-1.3-2.el6.x86_64.rpm from rhel-x86_64-server-6-s-epel
error was [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - &#34;The requested URL returned error: 500 Internal Server Error&#34;
  sr-kd-if-2.0-2.x86_64: failed to retrieve getPackage/sr-kd-if-2.0-2.x86_64.rpm from rhel-x86_64-server-6-s-deploy
error was [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - &#34;The requested URL returned error: 500 Internal Server Error&#34;</td>
        
          <td></td>
        
      </tr>
    
      
        <tr class='error'>
      
        <td rel="utctimestamp">2020-02-10T15:27:40.117-05:00</td>
        <td>/Stage[main]/sr-kd-if::V2_0/Package[sr-kd-if]/ensure</td>
        <td>err, package, sr-kd-if, class, sr-kd-if::v2_0, sr-kd-if, v2_0</td>
        <td>change from &#39;1.22-1&#39; to &#39;2.0-2&#39; failed: Could not update: Execution of &#39;/usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y update sr-kd-if-2.0-2&#39; returned 1: Error Downloading Packages:
  jq-1.3-2.el6.x86_64: failed to retrieve getPackage/jq-1.3-2.el6.x86_64.rpm from rhel-x86_64-server-6-s-epel
error was [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - &#34;The requested URL returned error: 500 Internal Server Error&#34;
  sr-kd-if-2.0-2.x86_64: failed to retrieve getPackage/sr-kd-if-2.0-2.x86_64.rpm from rhel-x86_64-server-6-s-deploy
error was [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - &#34;The requested URL returned error: 500 Internal Server Error&#34;</td>
        
          <td>/etc/SourceManagement/code/environments/env/modules/sr-kd-if/manifests/v2_0.pp:2</td>
        
      </tr>
    
      
        <tr class='positive'>
      
        <td rel="utctimestamp">2020-02-10T15:27:55.695-05:00</td>
        <td>/Stage[main]/Com::Ismt/fld::Ismt[1249 COM]/Exec[/bin/ksh -c &#39;source /usr/local/bin/src.host; /opt/hd/su/bin/sr-db-sc 1249 N COM&#39;]/returns</td>
        <td>notice, exec, fld::ismt, fld, ismt, class, com::ismt, com, fld::catalog, catalog, com::pr::v19_11_2, pr, v19_11_2</td>
        <td>executed successfully</td>
        
          <td>/etc/SourceManagement/code/environments/env/modules/fld/manifests/ismt.pp:7</td>
        
      </tr>
    
      
        <tr class='positive'>
      
        <td rel="utctimestamp">2020-02-10T15:27:55.696-05:00</td>
        <td>/Stage[main]/Com::Ismt/fld::Ismt[1249 COM]/Exec[/bin/ksh -c &#39;source /usr/local/bin/src.host; /opt/hd/su/bin/sr-db-sc 1249 N COM&#39;]</td>
        <td>info, exec, fld::ismt, fld, ismt, class, com::ismt, com, fld::catalog, catalog, com::pr::v19_11_2, pr, v19_11_2</td>
        <td>Scheduling refresh of Exec[/bin/chown pris01:dbaccgrp /opt/hd/su/tmp/*]</td>
        
          <td>/etc/SourceManagement/code/environments/env/modules/fld/manifests/ismt.pp:7</td>
        
      </tr>
    
      
        <tr class='positive'>
      
        <td rel="utctimestamp">2020-02-10T15:27:55.905-05:00</td>
        <td>/Stage[main]/Ismt_2615_pp::V1_0_0/fld::Ismt[ismt_2615]/Exec[/bin/chown pris01:dbaccgrp /opt/hd/su/tmp/*]</td>
        <td>notice, exec, fld::ismt, fld, ismt, ismt_2615, class, ismt_2615_pp::v1_0_0, ismt_2615_pp, v1_0_0</td>
        <td>Triggered &#39;refresh&#39; from 1 event</td>
        
          <td>/etc/SourceManagement/code/environments/env/modules/fld/manifests/ismt.pp:22</td>
        
      </tr>
    
      
        <tr class='positive'>
      
        <td rel="utctimestamp">2020-02-10T15:27:56.069-05:00</td>
        <td>Stage[main]</td>
        <td>info, stage</td>
        <td>Unscheduling all events on Stage[main]</td>
        
          <td></td>
        
      </tr>
    
      
        <tr class='positive'>
      
        <td rel="utctimestamp">2020-02-10T15:27:56.404-05:00</td>
        <td>SourceManagement</td>
        <td>notice</td>
        <td>Applied catalog in 35.89 seconds</td>
        
          <td></td>
        
      </tr>
    
  </tbody>
</table>

<h1>Metrics <a href="/download_report/myserv.foo.com/58964efb70ab87610ff4ce3fdbf46ce7dea54dac/metrics"><button style="float: right;" class="ui grey button"><span>Download</span></button></a></h1>
<table class="ui basic table compact">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Category</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Value</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    
      <tr>
        <td>resources</td>
        <td>changed</td>
        <td>5.0</td>
      </tr>
    
      <tr>
        <td>resources</td>
        <td>corrective_change</td>
        <td>5.0</td>
      </tr>
    
      <tr>
        <td>resources</td>
        <td>failed</td>
        <td>1.0</td>
      </tr>
    
      <tr>
        <td>resources</td>
        <td>failed_to_restart</td>
        <td>0.0</td>
      </tr>
    
      <tr>
        <td>resources</td>
        <td>out_of_sync</td>
        <td>6.0</td>
      </tr>
    
      <tr>
        <td>resources</td>
        <td>restarted</td>
        <td>2.0</td>
      </tr>
    
      <tr>
        <td>resources</td>
        <td>scheduled</td>
        <td>0.0</td>
      </tr>
    
      <tr>
        <td>resources</td>
        <td>skipped</td>
        <td>0.0</td>
      </tr>
    
      <tr>
        <td>resources</td>
        <td>total</td>
        <td>754.0</td>
      </tr>
    
      <tr>
        <td>time</td>
        <td>config_retrieval</td>
        <td>60.69</td>
      </tr>
    
      <tr>
        <td>time</td>
        <td>cron</td>
        <td>0.01</td>
      </tr>
    
      <tr>
        <td>time</td>
        <td>exec</td>
        <td>7.89</td>
      </tr>
    
      <tr>
        <td>time</td>
        <td>file</td>
        <td>6.95</td>
      </tr>
    
      <tr>
        <td>time</td>
        <td>file_line</td>
        <td>0.01</td>
      </tr>
    
      <tr>
        <td>time</td>
        <td>filebucket</td>
        <td>0.0</td>
      </tr>
    
      <tr>
        <td>time</td>
        <td>filesystem</td>
        <td>0.01</td>
      </tr>
    
      <tr>
        <td>time</td>
        <td>logical_volume</td>
        <td>2.35</td>
      </tr>
    
      <tr>
        <td>time</td>
        <td>mount</td>
        <td>0.0</td>
      </tr>
    
      <tr>
        <td>time</td>
        <td>package</td>
        <td>13.01</td>
      </tr>
    
      <tr>
        <td>time</td>
        <td>pe_anchor</td>
        <td>0.0</td>
      </tr>
    
      <tr>
        <td>time</td>
        <td>service</td>
        <td>0.76</td>
      </tr>
    
      <tr>
        <td>time</td>
        <td>total</td>
        <td>91.69</td>
      </tr>
    
      <tr>
        <td>time</td>
        <td>user</td>
        <td>0.0</td>
      </tr>
    
      <tr>
        <td>changes</td>
        <td>total</td>
        <td>5.0</td>
      </tr>
    
      <tr>
        <td>events</td>
        <td>failure</td>
        <td>1.0</td>
      </tr>
    
      <tr>
        <td>events</td>
        <td>success</td>
        <td>5.0</td>
      </tr>
    
      <tr>
        <td>events</td>
        <td>total</td>
        <td>6.0</td>
      </tr>
    
  </tbody>
</table>


        </div>
        <div class="one wide column"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="scroll-btn-top">
      <i class="large arrow up icon"></i>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

EDIT:

Last 25 lines of file after `grep -v -e '^\s*$' samplefile`

```html
      <tr>
        <td>changes</td>
        <td>total</td>
        <td>5.0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>events</td>
        <td>failure</td>
        <td>1.0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>events</td>
        <td>success</td>
        <td>5.0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>events</td>
        <td>total</td>
        <td>6.0</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
        </div>
        <div class="one wide column"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="scroll-btn-top">
      <i class="large arrow up icon"></i>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Last 25 lines of file after Go code example:

```html
      <tr>
        <td>events</td>
        <td>success</td>
        <td>5.0</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>events</td>
        <td>total</td>
        <td>6.0</td>
      </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>

        </div>
        <div class="one wide column"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="scroll-btn-top">
      <i class="large arrow up icon"></i>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello, Have you tried https://regex-golang.appspot.com/assets/html/index.html, it's a regex testing app specially made for golang. Also golang regex does not support lookahead/lookbehind which you are trying to use, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: In golang there are flags that modify how regex operates.  ```(?ms)``` is not any sort of lookahead or lookbehind but a specific part of configuring regexp behavior. It is like python regex behavior functions DOTALL and MULTILINE. You can read about the the flags under the *Groupings* section here: https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/syntax/

Comment: oh, my bad, I am not a regex expert and it looked like a lookahead. Anyway, I usualy test my regexes with that app to make sure it works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have this figured out. It appears the issue with the matches has to do with the use of start and end anchors. Using the `(?ms)` to change matching behavior from per *string* to per *line plus per string* throws the engine when `^` and `$` are used together. Simply using `(?ms)\s+$` matches only lines that are possibly combinations of `\t \n \r \f \v` . This produces the behavior I was looking for (only matching whitespace lines alone).

Answer (score 1):

`^` and `$` are *anchors* that match at the beginning or end of a line but *do not include the adjacent newline*. So all your regex does is to delete the whitespace on whitespace-only lines (and also to combine adjacent whitespace-only lines into one; see below), but it does not delete the initial or final newline.

You need to drop the multiline mode and use `(^|\n)` and `(\n|$)` to match the actual newlines, which will allow you to replace them. Note that you'll only want to replace one of them; otherwise, the lines surrounding whitespace-only lines will get joined. Also note that depending on which one you choose to replace, you might get an extra initial or final newline, so you might want to separately handle the initial and final set of whitespace-only lines (which may or may not exist).

---

(Old answer is below; maybe it'll be useful to someone else.)

`\s` also matches newlines, and `*` finds a maximal-length match. Therefore, adjacent whitespace-only lines will become one match.~~~

If you need to count individual lines, try using `*?` instead, which produces a non-greedy match (so it will stop once it reaches the `$`). Or use `[^\n\S]` instead of `\s`, which says "match anything except newlines or non-whitespace".

Comment: I don’t mind if it combines multiple lines as a single match. I’m not interested in how many lines are whitespace-only, I’m interested in REMOVING all whitespace-only lines. The golang code does not remove them all. It only removes a handful of lines. The file that is written on code conclusion still contains over 100 occurrences of whitespace-only lines.

Comment: I think you missed the part where I said "(newline only or spaces and newline)". Your suggestion would fail to accomplish what I'm attempting. If it helps you understand what exactly I'm trying to accomplish:

PCRE `grep -v -e '^\s*$' samplefile` does exactly what I want: removing all lines that are either `\n` alone or `    \n` or `\t\n` or any whitespace-type combinations. Additionally, my answer to my own question DOES remove the beginning and trailing newline.